# Does this inequality $\min\{a,b\}\leq ca+(1-c)b$ hold for $0\leq a\leq 1$, $0\leq b\leq 1$, and $0\leq c\leq 1$?

Tags: inequality

If $0\leq a\leq 1$, $0\leq b\leq 1$, and $0\leq c\leq 1$.

Does this inequality hold:
$$\min\{a,b\}\leq ca+(1-c)b?$$

I try to take counter example:

Let I take $a=0.4$, $b=0.25$, $c=0.1$.
$$\min\{a,b\}\leq ca+(1-c)b\iff 0.25\leq 0.04+0.225=0.265$$

Let I take $a=0.2$, $b=0.9$, $c=0.7$.
$$\min\{a,b\}\leq ca+(1-c)b\iff 0.2\leq 0.14+0.27=0.41.$$

and I can't find the counter example.

Now I assume that inequality hold. But I don't have idea to prove it. I have spent many time to think it and I can't prove it.

What the hint to prove it if this inequality hold?
$$\min\{a,b\}\leq ca+(1-c)b?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true inequality. To see this assume that $\min\{a,b\} =a $ then $$ca+(1-c)b \geq ca +(1-c) a =a =\min\{a,b\}$$
otherwise
$\min\{a,b\} =b $ and $$ca+(1-c)b \geq cb +(1-c) b =b =\min\{a,b\}.$$